# Imprimir dados da tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho no seguinte código:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT * FROM cadastro");
$exibe = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);
echo "<table>"; 
echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
echo "<td>".$exibe[1]."</td></tr>";
echo  "<tr><td>Sobrenome:</td>";
echo "<td>".$exibe[2]."</td></tr>";
```

Quer me dá o resultado:

```
Nome:   Olivaldo
Sobrenome:  Liveira
```

> Obs.: Dados passados via method POST no `<form>`

Quero trazer Todos os resultados, da minha tabela na tela,
Trazer no caso todas as linhas do ID.

Não sem por onde começar a pesquisar. Podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: @Nouzanadam é um relatório que está montando? ´

Comment: Quero criar quadro de consulta diário. Então decidi estudar php.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao mundo da TI, precisando estamos as ordens

Comment: @NatanMartinsNouzanadam Veja minha resposta abaixo, caso ela te ajudou, marque-a como resolvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um `while` para receber todos os registros do banco de dados.

```
echo "<table>"; 

$sql = mysqli_query($strcon, "SELECT * FROM cadastro");
while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)){

   echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
   echo "<td>".$exibe[1]."</td></tr>";
   echo  "<tr><td>Sobrenome:</td>";
   echo "<td>".$exibe[2]."</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Deus certo! obrigado!

Comment: @NatanMartinsNouzanadam aceite a pergunta como solucionada então

Comment: Sou novo por aqui ainda estou tentando econtrar na pagina onde faço isso kkkk